# Git: How do I set up SSH keys to access my remote repository from a second computer?

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit

I have a git repository on [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/), and a Windows machine I'm using with msysgit.  I set up an SSH key on that machine using ssh-keygen, which gave me some key files.  I copied the contents of the public key file into my personal settings in my Unfuddle account, and that works fine.

So what do I need to do to get it working on a second machine?  If I follow the same process, I'll have to put the new public key into my Unfuddle account, so presumably the old machine will stop working.  Is there some way I can get my second machine to use the same key as the first machine?

Thanks,
Grant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1/ If this the same user, you could copy your `~/.ssh/id_rsa`  and `id_rsa.pub` to your other machine home directory.

or:

2/ You should be able to register another public key to your unfuddle account, allowing you to manage one private key per machine.

Comment: Oh yeah!  I didn't notice that I could add extra public keys.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same private key to connect from the second machine, if they're both under your control.