# commiting to git repo from a second machine [Github]

Tags: git, github, commit

I am new to git. I could setup my git repository and started to using it a couple of days ago. (I am using Github)
Now I want to be able to commit from my other computer, so I setup git, try git clone git@addres.to.my.repo.git
but I got

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.___.___)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.___.___' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Do I need a certificate or something? in that case how can i do it?

Thanks in advance

Ignacio

UPDATE:
Sorry, I forgot to say that I am on Mac OS X.

Comment: If you let us know which OS you are using, that would be a big help!

Comment: This question is answered already but I found this question also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164745/git-how-do-i-set-up-ssh-keys-to-access-my-remote-repository-from-a-second-comput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide your SSH client (on the second machine) with the private key to match the public key you entered here:

https://github.com/account#ssh_bucket

If you're using OpenSSH on OS X (or Linux  or similar) this is likely to be `${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa`, which can simply copy from the first machine to the second.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your ssh creds are bouncing

I'm not sure if you can share key between two computers, but if you have a different public key for this second computer you can just go to your github account page https://github.com/account and add the second key there under SSH Public Keys?

http://help.github.com/key-setup-redirect
or maybe http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/